# Edit HL7 PID in transform step

Tags: javascript, mirth, mirth-connect

I'm trying to do some math with the PID in a HL7 message in the transform step.

This is the Code i have:

```
//add 100'000 to PID
var test;
var newPID;
test = parseInt(msg['PID']['PID.3']['PID.3.1'].toString(),10);
newPID = test + 100000;
tmp['PID']['PID.3']['PID.3.1'] = newPID;
```

The output is:

```
NaN
```

Sample of PID Segment:

```
PID||ABC123|987654|ALT789|PETTY^TOM^^^^||19781218|M||2106-3|10144 MAPLE AVE^^IRVINE^CA^92614||(949)123-1234|||||0053820452|220675537||AME||||1|||||
```

I always get the PID as a string and i can't convert it.
I'm new to Mirth and JavaScript so I'm glad for any help.

Comment: what is the output referring to? which variable?

Comment: the output refers to: `tmp['PID']['PID.3']['PID.3.1']`

Comment: Do you know for sure PID3.1 can always be converted to an integer?  Because parseInt will fail if its anything else (gives NaN).  -- so NaN + 1000000 = NaN as well

Comment: Yes PID.3.1 is always a number.

Comment: well it doesn't appear to be, I would check what this returns - msg['PID']['PID.3']['PID.3.1'], Another possibility is that its an empty string.  It will also result in NaN

Comment: Post a sample of your PID segment. It might have repeating patient IDs or something similar.

Comment: @erotavlas You were right the output from msg['PID']['PID.3']['PID.3.1'] ist: `undefined|`

Comment: @N.R. If you believe that data is coming, then you may have chosen a strict parsing mode and the actual reference to your PID is different. Other than that your code should work (plus including some additional verification and try-catch block).